# Why isn't my ActionListener working for my buttons?

Tags: java, css, swing, button, actionlistener

I'm having some trouble getting anything to happen when I click a button.

1. This is where I declare my buttons

   ```
   public class DoND extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

   public JButton btnsuit1, btnsuit2, btnsuit3, btnsuit4, btnsuit5, btnsuit6, btnsuit7, btnsuit8, btnsuit9, btnsuit10, btnsuit11, btnsuit12, btnsuit13, btnsuit14, btnsuit15, btnsuit16, btnsuit17, btnsuit18, btnsuit19, btnsuit20, btnsuit21, btnsuit22, btnsuit23, btnsuit24, btnsuit25, btnsuit26;

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       new DoND();
   }
   ```
2. This is all the detailed information about my buttons. (I have only given the detailed info of 2 buttons, but  there are 24 more buttons.)

   ```
   JButton btnsuit1 = new JButton();
   btnsuit1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images\\suitcases\\case1.png"));
   btnsuit1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 150));
   btnsuit1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
   btnsuit1.addActionListener(this);


   JButton btnsuit2 = new JButton();
   btnsuit2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images\\suitcases\\case2.png"));
   btnsuit2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 150));
   btnsuit2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
   btnsuit2.addActionListener(this);
   ```
3. This is where I add the buttons to my center panel. Then add my center panel to my main panel. Then add my main panel to my frame.

Center Panel

```
    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    centerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    centerPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    centerPanel.add(btnsuit1);
    centerPanel.add(btnsuit2);
```

Main Panel

```
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    mainPanel.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPanel.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainPanel.add(eastPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    mainPanel.add(westPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    mainPanel.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Frame

```
    setContentPane(mainPanel);
    setSize(3000, 1000);
    setTitle("Deal or No Deal");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
```

4. And this is my action listener.

   ```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

   if (e.getSource() == btnsuit1)
   {
       btnsuit1.setVisible(false);
   }

    if (e.getSource() == btnsuit2)
   {
       btnsuit2.setVisible(false);
   }
   ```

I don't know why nothing is happening, but I've searched around and I think there are a few possibilities.

a) The buttons to which I added ActionListener are different than the ones, ActionPerformed is searching for.

b) I have to extend ActionListener to the secondary panel in which all my buttons are.

I appreciate your help.

--

Grant

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of disconnected parts of your entire program? Does the actionPerformed() method ever get called? Does it ever enter those if statements? Use a debugger, or at least some print statements, to find out.

Comment: Ouch, that must have taken forever to code. A better way to have all those buttons stored and created would be an array and a for loop. A good tutorial on java arrays/for loops is [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm). Also since you are learning java, I would suggest a good book on it. The one I used is Introduction To Java Programming, comprehensive version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared your JButtons as class fields, but you never initialize them. Insted you create new JButton by:

```
JButton btnsuit1 = new JButton();
```

so, the `btnsuit1` in `btnsuit1.setVisible(false)` is probably null.
Try to change `btnsuit1` initialization on:

```
btnsuit1 = new JButton();
```

It should work.